# JQuery - Toggle an image inside of a div on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a toggled div with an image inside of it that toggles the scrolling of the next div:

```
<div class="section">
<img src="on.png"> Stuff </div>
<div class="under" style="height:302px;"> Hi </div>
```

Here's the JQuery for it:

```
$(".section").click(function(){
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle(1200);
});
```

How would I make it so on the `click` function for my div, it toggles the image to "off.png"? And if the `src` is "off.png", it toggles to "on.png"? Thanks. (Sorry I'm still a noob at JQuery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".section").click(function(){ 
   $("img").attr('src',  
                ($("img").attr('src') == 'http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/2772891/64c/png/power-off.png?v0'  
                    ? 'http://kiwianon.com/forums/Themes/Simple_Green/images/on.png'  
                    : 'http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/2772891/64c/png/power-off.png?v0' 
                     ) 
                )  
    }); 
});
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/fb9aa/4)

Comment: Could you break this down for me? This looks scary :O

Comment: I'm curious; not that it'd probably matter, but I tend to put IDs on things that I access directly. Are there any advantages/disadvantages to doing it the id-way vs. doing the short DOM traversal of your example? (If I was doing it your way I *would*, though, keep `$(this).closest("img")` in a local var to avoid doing it twice--or does jQuery cache it?)

Comment: @Ken: Take a lot on demo and just change urls

Comment: You answered my question again! :O I love you.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I have edited my code, closest() didn't work. but yes, it is better to call it only once and work with variable

Comment: Okay. +1 for looking up on/off images ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Do you think you could remove your upvote and upvote me again? I didn't gain any rep, now I would

Comment: Genesis....I would like to know more about the code so he could apply it to any other code. For example what does the ? and the : do in this code above. I don't get that part.

Comment: The ?: is the ternary operator; it's a short version of an if/else.

Comment: @genesis; I can't vote/re-vote unless the question is edited, so says the system--but yep, I will.

Comment: Done; don't know if it changed anything, but there ya' go :)

Comment: @Shawn31313: it is equivalent for `if ($("img").attr('src') == 'on.png'){ 
                    $("img").attr('src', 'off.png') } else{
                    $("img").attr('src', 'on.png' 
                     )`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".section").click(function(){

    var img = $(this).find("img").eq(0); //add an Id to your img tag so you can refine this selector. 
    if(img.attr("src") == "on.png")
    {
        img.attr("src","off.png");
    }
    else{
        img.attr("src","on.png");
    }

    $(this).next('div').slideToggle(1200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ken, this is very simple! Just use the code below:

```
$('.section').click(function(){
var currentimg=$(this).find('img').attr('src');
if(currentimg=="off.png"){
$(this).find('img').attr('src','on.png');
}
else{
$(this).find('img').attr('src','off.png');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(selector).attr("src", "theImageFilePath")` to change the image.

The state could be represented in several ways, including global/module variable, $(selector).data(...), or simply by checking the current value of the "src" attribute.